# How can I design a matrix that allows users to rate items in two or more categories?

Tags: forms, grid, ratings

Does anyone know a good way to show a double matrix question? For example where you need to rate stuff in 2 categorie!s (or more). Ive attached an example of what we came up with so far. The problem with this solution is that you have 2 clicks (1 for the dropdown, 1 for the option). We want to avoid this.

Example:

[image]

Maybe 2 sliders? Not alot of room for that tho.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps two columns of star-ratings? These only need a single click each, and are quite familiar for most users.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuFptR.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Note: the given stars don't nessecairily reflect my own ratings of these devices ;-)

Comment: For me this would be the easiest most recognizable way to rate multiple properties. It would fit nicely if the rating was just 1 through 5. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: Can you tell us what the valid rating ranges _are_ then? As you see, it is of importance to the proposed solutions.

Comment: In this particular case just 1 through 5 and 1 through 10. The client doesn't want to go for 1 scale for both properties.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many values each dropdown has and how many metrics per item. Sign up to a bunch of online survey services and see what solutions they offer (e.g. [survs.com](http://www.survs.com/))

A very common design pattern is spreading out the options with radio buttons or with sliders.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwZza8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This is probably the best option, only in my case the scales are different aswell. Where 1 category may be a rating in numbers 1 through 5, the other may be a rating like your mockup. I don't like the different scales at all, but thats the way the client wants it.